# Uncheck caps lock crashes Ubuntu installation

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I just got a new Razer Blade Stealth and I immediately proceeded to installing ubuntu on my laptop and erasing windows. What happened was that during installation, whenever I uncheck the caps lock on my keyboard, the computer crashes (the screen becomes fragmented? into gibberish).

Now I've finished installing it.. it is still crashing whenever I uncheck the caps lock.

Comment: Does your caps-lock have a light? If so, is it blinking when this happens?

Comment: It does have a light but it doesn't blink...

Comment: Oh, ok. I was checking because of this issue: [8.10 randomly freezing caps lock blinking flashing](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=968792)

Comment: Thanks Owen, I saw that one too but it doesn't seem like my problem

Comment: I reduced resolution to 1920*1080 and now it looks fine.

Comment: My graphic card is Intel HD 620 for 7th gen Core i7. I tried to update the driver using Intel Graphics Tool but that didn't do it.

Comment: I have the same problem. A few more details of the machine, maybe it helps somebody else: It's a Razer Blade Stealth w/ Intel Core i7-7500U, 16 GB RAM, 1TB SSD, 4K Display. OS: Kubuntu 16.10. Most of the time the crash happens when unlocking Caps Lock (second key release), sometimes it happens when locking Caps Lock the second time (third key press). It only happens on Caps Lock, not other keys.

Answer (score 2):

I have the "new" 2016 razer blade stealth; upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10. I had the same problems with the caps lock key crashing.

## Workaround: Disable Caps Lock

Obviously this completely disables the caps lock key, but it also prevents it from crashing the system.

## Ubuntu

Go to **Tweak tool -> typing -> caps lock key behavior**, change to "Caps Lock is disabled".

### Kubuntu

Go to **System Settings -> Hardware -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced**, in the section **Caps Lock key behavior** enable **Caps Lock is disabled**.

Comment: Sorry I just saw this. I think the problem with it is that the Intel HD 720(or 620 I forgot) is not fully supported. The driver keeps crashing the computer for no reason ( not just with Caps Lock, I actually had problem with normal shut down of the system). I did use xmod to completely disable Caps Lock like what you suggest but I ended up just not using Ubuntu coz of the shut down problem.

Comment: I was having constant problems with 16.04, I upgraded to 16.10 a couple days ago and it is MUCH more stable, I'm going on 2 days w/o a crash.

Comment: I think that this answer should be upvoted but not accepted, because this answer does not solve the problem, it only provides a workaround. Which is great as long as there's no solution, but still.

Comment: The tweak tool didn't have the typing option for me, but I found if I used dconf-editor to set `caps:none` in the xkb options, it worked.  I have the 2016 razer balde stealth.

Comment: This is not a viable solution.

Comment: Experiencing this issue as well and would love a better solution.