# Crash when toggling off CAPS LOCK

Tags: xorg, lightdm, 16.10, crash, capslock

Installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a Late 2016 Razer Blade Stealth.  When I hit CAPS LOCK, the light indicator for it comes on, and it works.  But when I hit it again to toggle it off, the screen gets covered in rectangular glitches, sometimes static plays on the speakers, and the device becomes unresponsive but does not reboot.  A crash of some sorts.

I'm not sure if this is related to X server, lightdm, or even a kernel crash?  I'm not really sure what logs to look at to even begin to start debugging.

If I disable lightdm with:

```
sudo systemctl stop lightdm.service
```

then hit ctrl+alt+F1 (no fn key) to get a text prompt, CAPS LOCK has no issue.

What could possibly be going wrong, and how do I start triaging this?

Edit 1: dupe of [Uncheck caps lock crashes Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/q/833411/644072), insufficient answer

Edit 2: some other things I've tried:

- ssh into the box to see if I can collect dmesg and xorg logs as per [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze).  ssh session becomes unresponsive after host crashes.
- try different desktop environments
- try different window managers

Comment: Have you installed all the updates?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade;`: yes.

Comment: try also `sudo apt full-upgrade`. BTW, since 16.04 `apt` is preferred instead of `apt-get` and with `apt` one uses `full-upgrade` instead of `dist-upgrade`. Keep update and a solution will come eventually. At the time of this writing there is none.

Answer (score 4):

I also have a New Razer Blade Stealth and I had the same problem but fixed it installing the razer keyboard driver for linux which you can find [here on GitHub](https://openrazer.github.io/#ubuntu) and disabling the built in keyboard driver.

There's a PPA for Ubuntu (16.04 and newer):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrazer/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openrazer-meta
```

If you get dependency errors when trying to install these driver packages make sure that you have enabled the `universe` repository in **Software & Updates**. There is also a development PPA (`ppa:openrazer/daily`).

Reboot, or insert the new module from the terminal:

```
sudo modprobe razerkbd
```

After installing the driver you should see it

```
lsmod | grep "razerkbd"
```

Second disable the built-in keyboard driver that causes the problem. First find the name of the driver.

```
xinput list
```

Disable it ("AT Raw Set 2 keyboard" in my case)

```
xinput set-prop "AT Raw Set 2 keyboard" "Device Enabled" 0
```

If this no longer produces an error, make the changes permanent.

```
cd /etc/X11/
sudo mkdir xorg.conf.d
cd xorg.conf.d/
sudo touch 20-razer.conf
sudo xed 20-razer.conf
```

Copy the following to **20-razer.conf**

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Disable built-in keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchProduct    "AT Raw Set 2 keyboard"
    Option          "Ignore"    "true"
EndSection
```

Reboot and check that the CAPS-lock key no longer produces the crash.

Answer (score 1):

[Jorge Garza's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/884599/527764) helps, but after suspend the problem was back. Adding the fix to  `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_razer` helps.

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> case $1 in
>      suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
>      # everything is fine
>      ;;
>      resume|thaw)
>      xinput set-prop "AT Raw Set 2 keyboard" "Device Enabled" 0
>     ;;
> esac
> ```

as explained [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux#caps-lock-issue)

Answer (score 0):

This one is to disable the caps lock on your keyboard so that you dont accidentally crash your razerblade stealth laptop:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option caps:ctrl_modifier  gsettings set

org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"
```

Comment: You've copied this answer to three separate questions.  If the questions are that similar that the answer is identical, and the questions are almost the same, then you should flag the questions for closure as duplicates, not repost your answer three times.

Answer (score 0):

Fellas, I found the solution for this issue. I tried it around 10 minutes ago and my machine hasn't frozen yet.
Create a script with the following content:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = 0x0000
```

I called mine `killcapslock`
After that, from your terminal, run:

```
xmodmap killcapslock
```

After that, your caps lock should no longer lock your PC.

All credit goes to:

https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-kill-caps-lock-your-linux-desktop/

I'm using a Razer Blade 2016, 12.5", Intel 620HD integrated graphics