# Restore previous drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel, keyboard, laptop

I was following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873626/crash-when-toggling-off-caps-lock#) to help me fix an issue where my late 2016 razer blade stealth would crash on me whenever I toggle the cap locks key but it didn't work. I did the command where it installed a bunch of these stuff

> sudo apt install python3-razer razer-kernel-modules-dkms razer-daemon
>   razer-doc

and when I tried looking up this

> lsmod | grep "razerkbd"

it couldn't find it. Now whenever i restart my laptop, chrome takes a good minute to open up and some stuff even lags, like when I try opening the terminal or right clicking. I want to uninstall all those razer stuff I installed and restore my computer to how it was previously before those razer installs. I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and this is the first time I have ever installed another OS on a computer, sorry for my inexperience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To uninstall, you should be able to:**

**Note**: if these steps produce any errors, **stop** and do not continue.

In `terminal`...

```
xinput set-prop "AT Raw Set 2 keyboard" "Device Enabled" 1
```

Try your regular keyboard. If it doesn't work, stop.

```
sudo rm -i /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-razer.conf

sudo apt-get purge python3-razer razer-kernel-modules-dkms razer-daemon razer-doc
```

Comment: I did what you told me to do but my computer is still acting up. Chrome is taking about 5 minutes to boot up and when it does, the rest of the computer acts up. I tried opening my terminal and it wouldn't and then 4 opened at the time.  Any ideas? I am thinking the drivers arent uninstalled and I need to install the previous drivers.

Comment: @anonuser1234 Did you reboot the computer? Does the problem you describe happen if you log into the `guest` or other accounts?

Comment: I rebooted it, and I'm logging into my own personal account

Comment: I needed to know if the problem with Chrome happens in **another** account than your own.

Comment: the guest account works fine. So it's user session problem?

Comment: Yes. In your own account, in `terminal` do `ps auxc | grep orca`. Report back.

Comment: You actually asked two separate questions... "Restore previous drivers" and "Chrome/terminal problems". My answer addressed the first problem. Please accept it to close this question, and start a new question titled "Chrome and terminal slow to open" along with your description, and we'll take care of it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I am still not sure what caused the issue but after researching a bit more, I found this

[Terminal appears with much delay when shortcut is used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911946/terminal-appears-with-much-delay-when-shortcut-is-used)

and did what he said

Open Startup Application and add new

1. Add new
2. Name : terserah
3. Command : killall gnome-keyring-daemon
4. Comment : terserah

And everything works as is.

Except for my cap locks crashing my computer...

Comment: That's not the right fix, and it will cause problems later.

Comment: @heynnema what problems will it cause?

Comment: I would expect password or SSH problems.