# Chrome and terminal slow to open

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I had a question before that uninstalled some drivers 
[Restore previous drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948092/restore-previous-drivers/948152#948152)

however I still have issues with startups on Chrome and my terminal lagging via crtl+alt+t. I followed this answer

[Terminal appears with much delay when shortcut is used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911946/terminal-appears-with-much-delay-when-shortcut-is-used)

But the user heynnema warned me this will cause me issues in the future. Is there a way to completely fix the delay startup I am having with chrome and the terminal? Thank you

Comment: Which answer did you try (you linked the question) and what exactly did you get warned of? The current solution for your problem should be to uninstall the `dbus-user-session` package - at least until a fix for its bug is available. This is described e.g. in the second half of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/916263/367990) or in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/936051/367990). You can also check the corresponding [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825).

Comment: If I recall, the terminal worked fine in the guest account, yes? Is your normal account set to log in without a password, or is a password required? In your own account, in `terminal` do `ps auxc | grep orca`. Report back.

Comment: @ByteCommander I warned that creating a startup item that contained `killall gnome-keyring-daemon` might cause password or SSH problems.

Comment: @heynnema If he's experiencing the bug I mentioned (which I strongly believe), the best way would be to uninstall `dbus-user-session` anyway, if possible. But thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ByteCommander I agree, and that's probably what we'll do, but I've got one or two more tricks up my sleeve that I want to try, and right now, I'm just waiting for confirmation of a few things from the OP... like if I remember correctly, the problem didn't occur in the guest account...

Comment: @heynnema, @ByteCommander, Yes the problem did not occur on the guest account. I'll try the `dbus-user-session`. Sorry for the wait, I had to leave.

Comment: @heynnema, I tried `ps auxc | grep orca` but nothing was found. What should I try next? Also on my own personal account, I need a password

Comment: @anonuser1234 Don't do the `dbus-user-session` thing yet. I didn't expect the `ps auxc` to find anything, but it was a quick hunch. Remove the startup item with `killall`. And now lets talk about the password on your account. When Ubuntu boots, it drops directly into your account, yes? After removing the `killall`, reboot, and immediately start the `Passwords and Keys` app, and look at the `login` keychain. Is there an open or closed padlock next to the name? Also, tell me what you have in your `Startup Applications`.

Comment: @heynnema, So I am not sure what fixed it. I did the `dbus-user-session` but the problem came back after I rebooted. So then I decided to install the razer drivers one more time but this time with secure boot disable since my laptop is UEFI. The cap locks work now and Chrome and my terminal boot up correctly even after I got rid of all the extra things I added in the Startup Applications. Like I said, I am not sure what exactly fix it but it might have been installing the drivers correctly.
Thank you for all of your help.